# How to list all supported locales from Luxon or Intl?

Tags: javascript, luxon

I'm trying to replace [Moment.js](https://github.com/moment/moment/) with the [Luxon](https://github.com/moment/luxon/) library in the open source project [Koia](https://github.com/centeractive/koia).

`moment.locales()` lists all locales that have been loaded and are available to use. These values are used in a drop-down list, which allows the user to define the locale to be used for converting date/time values when loading a file to the web application.

This is the existing method in the [DateTimeUtils](https://github.com/centeractive/koia/blob/master/src/app/shared/utils/date-time-utils.ts) class.

```
/**
 * @returns all available moment.js locals
 */
static listMomentLocals(): string[] {
  return moment.locales();
}
```

I cannot find an equivalent function in Luxon. I know that Luxon internally uses [`Intl`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl). Therefore I tried to find an appropriate function on `Intl`, with no success however.

How can I obtain all supported locales from Luxon or `Intl`?

Comment: Luxon doesn't bundle locales, that's one of the three key points highlighted right at the top https://moment.github.io/luxon/#/, it uses https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl.

Comment: In this case, what would be the list used by them? Wasn't able to find in the provided link